# Angular testing - Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

So, im writing my first tests so im following tutorials but i've got and error and cant really figure it out:

```
import { BackupTasksComponent } from './backup-tasks.component';
import { BackupUsersService } from '../backup-users.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs';

let mockUsers = [
    {
        name: 'test',
        age: 12,
        adult: false
    }
];

class MockBackupUsersService {
    getBackupUsers(){
        return new Observable((observer: Observer<Array<any>>) => {
            observer.next(mockUsers);
        });
    }
}

let fixture: ComponentFixture<BackupTasksComponent>;
let component: BackupTasksComponent;

describe('Component', ()=>{
    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() =>{
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [BackupTasksComponent],
            providers: [
                {provide: BackupUsersService, useClass: MockBackupUsersService}
            ]
        })
        TestBed.compileComponents().then(()=>{
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BackupTasksComponent);
            component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        })
    }))
        it('Should make a call to a service to getBackupUsers', ()=>{
            spyOn(component.BackupUsersService, 'getBackupUsers' as never).and.callThrough();
    
            component.getBackupUsers();
    
// it says "Property 'getBackupUsers' does not exists on type (BackupUsersService: any, arg1: string) => void. 
            expect(component.BackupUsersService.getBackupUsers).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
    
})
```

The problem is described in the last lines of code. I want to test if my component is calling a service method 'getBackupUsers'

Comment: But component does not have `component.getBackupUsers()`. `getBackupUsers()` exists only in `BackupUsersService`.

Comment: Both - service and component have getBackupUsers method, and error appears on the last line where i try to call getBackupUsers from BackupUsersService

Comment: Okay. Shouldn't it expect to have called a method? Isn't expecting `getBackupUsers` to have been called the same as to expect a variable to have been called if it is without the `()`?
`expect(component.BackupUsersService.getBackupUsers()).toHaveBeenCalled();`